# Ubuntu fails on Boot Up

Tags: 11.10, dual-boot, boot-failure, asus, ati

I have a dual-boot of windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10. AMD Phenom-II 4-core processor, and an Asus motherboard.

So here's what happens, I turn on my computer my machine does its start-up process, then the grub comes up and I choose Ubuntu. The Ubuntu logo comes up with the five dots below it. It will do this for 15 seconds, then I get a screen with different processes starting such as Bluetooth and components starting up and all are accepted, then it will freeze on a midi process with this text.

*Starting TiMidity++ ALSA midi emulation...                     [OK]

I left it like this for 8 hours and there were no changes on the screen. I have tried some fixes for issues similar to mine but none have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remembered that there were 2 failed Remastersys backups on my Ubuntu partition that had filled it. After I found the rm command and used it in the recovery console my Ubuntu installation started up normally.